# Pthread Passing Function to Pool

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, threadpool

I am working on creating a threadpool from scratch as part of an assignment and am able to create the thread pool and then pass each created thread a function that constantly loops. My question is how can I accept the input and pass it to an already executing pthread. After figuring this out I will add mutexes to lock the function to a specific thread, but I am unable to get to that part.

```
class ThreadPool{
public:
    ThreadPool(size_t threadCount);
    int dispatch_thread(void *(dispatch_function(void *)), void *arg);
    bool thread_avail();
    int numThreads;
    pthread_t * thread;
    pthread_mutex_t * mutexes;
};


int ThreadPool::dispatch_thread(void *(dispatch_function(void *)), void *arg){

  flag = 1;
//This is where I would like to pass the function the running pthread
}

void *BusyWork(void *t)
{
  while(true){
  //This is where I would like to run the passed function from each thread
  //I can run the passed function by itself, but need to pass it to the threadpool
  }
}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t threadCount){
 pthread_t thread[threadCount];

 for(t=0; t<threadCount; t++) {
 //printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
 rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, BusyWork, (void *)t); 
 }
}

void *test_fn(void *par)
{
   cout << "in test_fn " << *(int *)par << endl;
}

int main (){
  ThreadPool th(3);
  int max = 100;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    max = 100 * i;
    th.dispatch_thread(test_fn, (void *)&max);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: shared data + (mutex, condition variable) should do it

Comment: I agree, I just don't know the proper way to pass the void *(dispatch_function(void *)), void *arg) arguments of the dispatch_thread function as a condition variable or a way to have it declared globally. I didn't know if there was a certain syntax-based way to do this or if there was a completely new option available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best pattern that I can think of is to use some sort of queue to pass messages to the thread-pool. These messages may contain functions to be run as well as some control messages for shutting down the thread-pool. As you already have guessed, the queue will have to be thread safe.

A simple approach for the queue is to use a fixed size array which you turn into a circular buffer. The array will have a Mutex to lock it when accessing the array and a Condition Variable to awaken the thread-pool thread.

When putting an item on the queue, we lock the mutex, add to the queue and then signal the thread-pool with the Condition Variable.

Each running thread in the in the thread pool will start life by locking the mutex and waiting on the condition varaible (which automaticall unlocks the Mutex). When awoken it will remove the item from the queue, and then unlock the mutex. It is now free do its stuff. When finished it goes to sleep until re-signaled.

As general advice, avoid sharing memory between threads because this either leads to race conditions (if access is not protected) or leads to interlocking (if access is locked). Also avoid locking a mutex when performing any long running operation such as calling new (malloc), delete (free) or any system calls.

Comment: So if I were to use the queuing method as you described would I create a struct that contains the function name as well as the arguments passed to it. If so then what would be a way to extract that information from the dispatch_function. I have had difficulties extracting the function name.

Comment: The queue will contain entries (which will be a struct). a really simple idea is for the struct to contain a function point of signature void fn(void*). With a second parameter of void* . Alternatively you can pass object that contain the function void run(). There are many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing before reading your comment. Thank you for the help.